# How to update Android Emulator to new Version. VS

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use Hardware acceleration, following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin)

When i'm opening my emulator i'm gotting the error message:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
> acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and
> usable. CPU acceleration status: Please disable Hyper-V before using
> the Android Emulator.  Start a command prompt as Administrator, run
> 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.

I have installed the preview version and enable everything in windows resources,
my windows version is 1803.

The only think i could not do is update my Android Emulator cause i don't find where to do it.
My Android Emulator version is:
[image]

Any idea how to update this or what is causing this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure your Hyper-V has been disabled.

Comment: Start a command prompt as Administrator, run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`, reboot.

Comment: Also please note, the screenshot you posted above is `Android SDK Manager`. If you want to create a higher version of Android emulator(eg: Android emulator with Android version 8.1), please use the [Android Device Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin#verifying-haxm-installation).

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose which one of the 2 virtualization techniques. 
I suppose that you have HAXM installed, so you will need to disable Hyper-V from the Windows Features dialogue or with the command stated. 
Then, complete the installation of the HAXM engine by running the installer from the folder `extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` of your Android SDK. 
Beware that HAXM runs only on [specific CPUs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005486/processors.html).
For the other question, in order to update the emulator, you should install the latest `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` of your SDK platform. You can then proceed to update your Android Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable Hyper-V (as described above) and - in addition - had to enable "HW acceleration" (set some options) in the **Bios** to my machine, to enable HAXM (options depend on HW vendor).